Docker volumes and MySQL data access
I am currently writing an automated check-in system in flask with a MySql database. I want the code to run indefinitely, so I've deployed the app and database on Docker. This way I can keep iterating on my main computer while running a less recent version on an old computer of mine.
My issue, however, is that between the two computers the MySql databases are different and the MySql database running locally on my main computer is also different than the database when I run docker on my main computer. I want to be able to query information and still use the MySql database in my command line as I develop the app. My main computer is running MySQL locally on MacOS.
Currently I have the databases set to run as Docker volumes, but I'm not sure that's the best option. If anyone has insights on the way to best persistently run a database in docker across devices (or at least how to make it so my other computer and docker volumes query and add information to the database running locally on my computer) I would appreciate it!
Here is my compose.yaml file:
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SQL_PASS=/run/secrets/db-password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/db-password
      - TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=/run/secrets/twilio-sid
      - TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=/run/secrets/twilio-token
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    secrets:
      - db-password
      - twilio-sid
      - twilio-token

  db:
    # We use a mariadb image which supports both amd64 & arm64 architecture
    #image: mariadb:10-focal
    # If you really want to use MySQL, uncomment the following line
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: ['CMD-SHELL', 'mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 --password="$$(cat /run/secrets/db-password)" --silent']
      interval: 3s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 30s
    secrets:
      - db-password
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/mysql/data/callassure:/db-data
      - type: bind
        source: ./initial-data
        target: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=callassure
      - MYSQL_USER=mysql
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/db-password
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/db-password
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060

volumes:
  db-data:

secrets:
  db-password:
    file: db/password.txt
  twilio-sid:
    file: db/sid.txt
  twilio-token:
    file: db/auth.txt

and my Dockerfile:
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

# Comments are provided throughout this file to help you get started.
# If you need more help, visit the Dockerfile reference guide at
# https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-reference/

# Want to help us make this template better? Share your feedback here: https://forms.gle/ybq9Krt8jtBL3iCk7

ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.9.6
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Keeps Python from buffering stdout and stderr to avoid situations where
# the application crashes without emitting any logs due to buffering.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Install required system packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    default-libmysqlclient-dev \
    build-essential \
    pkg-config \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create a non-privileged user that the app will run under.
# See https://docs.docker.com/go/dockerfile-user-best-practices/
ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser

# Download dependencies as a separate step to take advantage of Docker's caching.
# Leverage a cache mount to /root/.cache/pip to speed up subsequent builds.
# Leverage a bind mount to requirements.txt to avoid having to copy them into
# into this layer.
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Switch to the non-privileged user to run the application.
USER appuser

# Copy the source code into the container.
COPY . .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the application.
CMD ["flask", "run", "-h", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "8000"]


What's the specific problem you're running into?  It looks like you're mounting the MySQL data directory in the wrong place so data isn't getting persisted across restarts, and Compose expose: does pretty much nothing, but the Compose setup seems fine.  Your dev and prod environments will be completely separate and that's fine.

@DavidMaze The databases are running with different data/as different instances, but I'd like the queries and data insertions to all be within the same database. I want to go from having 2 independent databases to one database instance that all my computers connect to. How would I change things so that my MySQL data does go to the right place? What do you mean my 2 environments will be separate?

Assuming both computers are running on the same network your setup seems ready to achieve exactly what you want.
If I understand your request correctly, you want your automated system + all your dev work to point to the same single MySQL database running on your old computer. If so, you just need to match the host parameter when connecting from your new computer to the IP address of your old computer.
You will have to change your server to not assume that the MySQL database is on the 127.0.0.1 IP. For example, adding an ENV environment variable:
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SQL_HOST=${SQL_HOST}
      - SQL_PASS=/run/secrets/db-password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=/run/secrets/db-password
      - TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=/run/secrets/twilio-sid
      - TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=/run/secrets/twilio-token
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    secrets:
      - db-password
      - twilio-sid
      - twilio-token

You can now create different .env files on your old and new computers with different values for the SQL_HOST environment variable, which you can then use in your Flask app.
